# Update costume field before registration the new user in Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails application and using Devise for authenticating in app. 
This Rails app is in API mode. I added some costume fields in devise Users model:

```
## Costume fields
field :ip, type: String
field :role, type: String , default: 'client'
```

As you can see, I wan to add IP address of user, during signup action of devise. I want to tell devise that when a you got a new "signup" request, please before adding user into the database, get user IP and add it to fields then save new user in to database like this:

```
{
  email: 'test@example.com',
  encrypted_password: "sg4rgtgesrre5erghtr5etrgtrrergre55trgf....",
  ip: '1.2.2.1'    // The user rote IP
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you had set up the devise controller

in your registration controller for user you can modify the script

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)
  resource.ip = '1.1.1.1'
  resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.persisted?
   ....# rest of the create action code
 end
```

but this wont save the ip to the database before saving.... but the ip value will be added to the user object for further saving.

Comment: I added this code but still not working: def create
```build_resource(sign_up_params.merge(ip: request.ip))
    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
     puts 'doneeee'
  end```

Comment: did you permitted the :ip in your permitted attributes list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the modify create action in `Devise::RegistrationController` for this work.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/40f02ae69baf7e9b0449aaab2aba0d0e166f77a3/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L17

Your main goal is to modify the `sign_up_params` content. You can do it 2 ways:

1. You can create your your own params like

   ```
   def user_sign_up_params
    sign_up_params.merge ip: request.ip
   end
   ```

   and change the above line  `build_resource(user_sign_up_params)`
2. You can add ip on place like `build_resource(sign_up_params.merge(ip: request.ip))`